# Python Kivy FileChooser

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to learn kivy through the documentation and I've been having issues with FileOpener. I suck at 0bject-oriented programming so I've been having trouble with FileOpener since most of the examples are in OOP. I'm trying to create a basic notepad with the ability to open text files.

I tried making the OpenFilePage class inherit from the LoginPage class so that I can access to the kivy text input widget but that just overlayed them.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

import os
cwd = os.getcwd()

class WelcomeWindow(FloatLayout):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):

    pass
class LoginPage(Screen):
    def saveTxt(self):
        with open("notes.txt","w") as note_file:
            note_file.write(self.ids.textbox.text)
            note_file.close()

    def clearBox(self):
        self.ids.textbox.text=""

class OpenFilePage(Screen):
    textbox = ObjectProperty(None)

    def openFile(self,path,f_name):
        with open(os.path.join(path, f_name[0])) as file:
            self.textbox.text = file.read()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return WindowManager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

```
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: [1,1]

<BubbleButton>:
    size_hint: (1, 1)
    pos_hint: {'x': 0}
    background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)

<WindowManager>:
    LoginPage:
    OpenFilePage:

<LoginPage>:
    textbox:textbox
    name: "main"
    id:LoginPage
    orientation: "vertical"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, .9)
            TextInput:
                id: textbox
                text:"Clear and start typing"
                multiline: True
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, .1)
            orientation:"horizontal"
            BubbleButton:
                id: OpenB
                text:"Open"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "OpenFilePage"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

            BubbleButton:
                id :clearButton
                text:"clear"
                on_release: root.clearBox()

            BubbleButton:
                id:saveButton
                text:"save"
                on_release:root.saveTxt()

<OpenFilePage>:
    name: "OpenFilePage"
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: (.2, 1)
                orientation: "vertical"
                BubbleButton:
                    text:"Back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "main"
                        root.manager.transition.direction= "left"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                FileChooserIconView:
                    id:filechooser
                    on_selection: self.openFile(filechooser.path,filechooser.selection)
```

The error I get when opening a file and assigning the textinput.text variable to what the opened file reads is:

```
INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1406, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1442, in on_touch_up
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1201, in on_touch_up
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 304, in on_touch_up
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 551, in on_touch_up
     return super(FileChooserController, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 304, in on_touch_up
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 571, in on_touch_up
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_up', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/scrollview.py", line 895, in on_touch_up
     if self.dispatch('on_scroll_stop', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/scrollview.py", line 934, in on_scroll_stop
     self.simulate_touch_down(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/scrollview.py", line 642, in simulate_touch_down
     ret = super(ScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/scatter.py", line 526, in on_touch_down
     if super(Scatter, self).on_touch_down(touch):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 395, in <module>
     on_touch_down: self.collide_point(*args[1].pos) and ctx.controller().entry_touched(self, args[1])
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/filechooser.py", line 615, in entry_touched
     self.selection = [abspath(join(self.path, entry.path)), ]
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ListProperty.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 544, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 599, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1096, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "/home/mihle/Workspace/Python/GUI/my.kv", line 65, in <module>
     on_selection: root.openFile(filechooser.path,filechooser.selection)
   File "main.py", line 31, in openFile
     self.textbox.text = file.read()
 AttributeError: 'OpenFilePage' object has no attribute 'textbox'
```

Comment: there is something wrong with your kv codes and the errors you are displaying. 1. `File "/home/mihle/Workspace/Python/GUI/my.kv", line 65, in <module>
     on_selection: root.openFile(filechooser.path,filechooser.selection)` you have this in the errors but have `on_selection: self.openFile(filechooser.path,filechooser.selection)` in the pasted kv code .                        2. OpenFilePage doesnt have any widget with the `id:textbox` there so that wont work either